# Load confirm dialog message for Rails remotely

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails has a notion of unobtrusive javascript. I can use `confirm` to add a confirmation dialog for buttons or links.

This works. However, I have to provide a confirmation text at the the moment when rails app returns a page.

The issue is that I had to do quite a lot of crunching for the confirmation message. Crunching a lot of numbers isn't big deal when it needs to be done one.

However, when I display a Rails list (with 10 items on it), I had to do this crunching 10 times.

I was trying to figure out whether there is a way to do this just in time (do remote call to do crunching and return a message when a user clicks on a button/link)

Comment: Sure, there's probably lots of ways. Give some stuff a try and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html